# Check if file is sparse

Tags: c++, .net, file, winapi, ntfs

I'd like to check if file located on ntfs file system is [sparse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/en-en/library/windows/desktop/aa365564.aspx). What function I need to use to check that?

As I know sparse files contain data pieces in separate streems so I tryed to list alternate streams via `FindFirstStreamW` and `FindNextStreamW`, but it doesn't show anything interesting with sparse files.

Comment: No, sparse files are not those with alternate streams. That is a completely different and orthogonal feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Win32, use the [`GetFileAttributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944.aspx) function, checking the result if the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE` attribute is present.

In .NET, use the [`File.GetAttributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes.aspx) method, checking the result if the `FileAttributes.SparseFile` attribute is present.